# batch processing in a simple shell

Tags: c++, shell

Hey folks I am making a batch command function in a shell that reads from a txt file and pipes it to a child to exec.

I'm having an issue with exec. I suspect it is something with the null terminator. If I execl with an L and an explicit (char*)NULL the exec runs. If I execvp(argIn[0],argIn) nothing runs and returns a -1. If I execvp with an explicit (char*)NULL I get an error cannot convert char* to char* constant*. I read somewhere that it might be the g++ compiler giving me the error but the gcc compiler wouldn't give the error. Right now it won't compile with gcc though so I'm not sure if that's true. But it shouldn't need the explicit terminator anyway. I'm not sure if the '\0' I have stored is being passed to the exec right. It checks out when I pass it to other functions though so maybe that's not the solution.

Second, my for loop won't exec more than once which I think is more to do with the first solution. I can get the execl to fork with an index but I can't increment the index to point to the right token the next time through because the child should be wiping out my index right?

Anyway it's been 3 weeks of digging to figure out what's wrong. I failed the assignment. Probably going to fail the class. I don't know what else to try. So any help I would appreciate.

My question is why would the exec function not execute the program? I'm passing execvp(program name, program name, option, option, '\0') and not getting a result.

or

execl(program name, program name[index], option[index+1], option[index+1], (char*)NULL) and getting a result. They both seem to be following the parameters but only one is giving me a result.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<unistd.h>

using namespace std;
int makearg(char s[], char**args[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char **argIn;
    int argCount;
    int pos = 0;
    char str[500];
    pid_t pid = fork();

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
            if(pid == 0)
            {
                while(fgets(str, 500, stdin) != NULL)
                    {
                        cout << "String loaded: " << str;
                        argCount = makearg(str, &argIn);
                execvp(argIn[0],argIn); //nothing exec
//              execl(argIn[0],argIn[0],argIn[1],argIn[2],(char*)NULL); //exec but requires index. 
        else if(pid < 0)
        {
                   perror("fork() error");
                   exit(-1);
        }
        else if(pid > 0)
        {
            cout << "Parent waiting" << endl;
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}



int makearg(char s[], char**args[])
{
    int counter = 1;
    int tokenLen = 1;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    char arg1[50];
    char * arg2;

    strcpy(arg1, s);
    //Count white space.
    while (arg1[j] != '\0')
    {
        if (arg1[j] == ' ' || arg1[j] == '\0' || arg1[j] == '\n')
        {
            counter++;
        }
        j++;
    }

    //Allocate the number of rows to be pointed to.
    args[0] = (char**) malloc(counter + 1);
    if(args[0] == NULL)
        exit(1);


    //Allocate the size of the c string arrays
    j = 0;
    while(arg1[j] != '\0')
    {
        if (arg1[j] == ' ' || arg1[j] == '\0' || arg1[j] == '\n')
        {
            (*args)[i] = (char*)(malloc(tokenLen));
            if((*args)[i] == NULL)
                exit(1);

            tokenLen = 0;
            i++;
        }

        j++;
        tokenLen++;
    }

    (*args)[i] = (char*)(malloc(tokenLen));
    if ((*args)[i] == NULL)
        exit(1);

    //reset values
    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    //Set arg2 to point to args row head. Transfer values from arg1 to arg2.
    arg2 = ((*args)[i]);
    while(arg1[j] != '\0')
    {
        if (arg1[j] != ' ' && arg1[j] != '\0' && arg1[j] != '\n')
        {
            arg2[k] = arg1[j];
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            arg2[k] = '\0';
            i++;
            k = 0;
            arg2 = ((*args)[i]);
        }
        j++;

    }

    arg2[k] = '\0';

    if (counter < 1)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Comment: What. Is your question?

Comment: The question is. Why isn't the exec function working given the parameters described.

Comment: What happens instead of "something exec"?

Comment: Also why don't you know which language you're using?

Comment: "What happens instead of "something exec"? What?

I'm using cout for output streams. I didn't want to confuse anyone assuming it was entirely c code.

Comment: Why are you trolling my question? This has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: @cba1067950 That's not _trolling_! There's no language c/c++, pick one **seriously**!

Comment: C++ is the language c/c++. You can't pick one. And it is trolling. This discussion doesn't contribute anything to a solution for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your posted code, updated it to fix build errors and ran. I executed the simple command "ls" but I got the message

```
String loaded: ls
ls: cannot access '': No such file or directory
```

That indicated to me that `makearg` is not working correctly. Then, I added a function to help with diagnosing the problem.

```
void printArguments(char **args)
{
   for ( int j = 0; args[j] != NULL; ++j )
   {
      printf("args[%d]: %s\n", j, args[j]);
   }
}
```

and added a call to it from `main`, right after the call to `makearg`.

```
        argCount = makearg(str, &argIn);
        printArguments(argIn);
```

I got the output:

```
String loaded: ls
args[0]: ls
args[1]: 
ls: cannot access '': No such file or directory
```

That indicated to me that `makearg` was not dealing with the end of the line correctly. It creates an empty argument.

I added couple of functions to trim whitespaces from the left and from the right. After that, the child process was able to execute "ls" correctly.

Here's the updated program.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<unistd.h>

using namespace std;
int makearg(char s[], char**args[]);

void printArguments(char **args)
{
   for ( int j = 0; args[j] != NULL; ++j )
   {
      printf("args[%d]: %s\n", j, args[j]);
   }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char **argIn;
   int argCount;
   char str[500];
   pid_t pid = fork();

   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   {
      if(pid == 0)
      {
         while(fgets(str, 500, stdin) != NULL)
         {
            cout << "String loaded: " << str;
            argCount = makearg(str, &argIn);
            printArguments(argIn);
            execvp(argIn[0],argIn); //nothing exec
         }
      }
      else if(pid < 0)
      {
         perror("fork() error");
         exit(-1);
      }
      else if(pid > 0)
      {
         cout << "Parent waiting" << endl;
         wait(NULL);
      }
   }
   return 0;
}

void trimWhiteSpacesLeft(char s[])
{
   int i = 0;

   for ( ; isspace(s[i]); ++i );

   if ( i == 0 )
   {
      return;
   }

   int j = 0;
   for (; s[i] != '\0'; ++j, ++i )
   {
      s[j] = s[i];
   }
   s[j] = '\0';
}

void trimWhiteSpacesRight(char s[])
{
   int len = strlen(s);
   int i = len-1;
   for ( ; i >= 0; --i )
   {
      if ( !isspace(s[i]) )
      {
         break;
      }
   }
   s[i+1] = '\0';
}

int makearg(char s[], char**args[])
{
   int counter = 1;
   int tokenLen = 1;
   int i = 0;
   int j = 0;
   int k = 0;
   char arg1[50];
   char * arg2;

   strcpy(arg1, s);

   // Trim whitespaces from both ends.
   trimWhiteSpacesLeft(arg1);
   trimWhiteSpacesRight(arg1);

   //Count white space.
   while (arg1[j] != '\0')
   {
      if (arg1[j] == ' ' || arg1[j] == '\0' )
      {
         counter++;
      }
      j++;
   }

   //Allocate the number of rows to be pointed to.
   args[0] = (char**) malloc(counter + 1);
   if(args[0] == NULL)
      exit(1);


   //Allocate the size of the c string arrays
   j = 0;
   while(arg1[j] != '\0')
   {
      if (arg1[j] == ' ' || arg1[j] == '\0' || arg1[j] == '\n')
      {
         (*args)[i] = (char*)(malloc(tokenLen));
         if((*args)[i] == NULL)
            exit(1);

         tokenLen = 0;
         i++;
      }

      j++;
      tokenLen++;
   }

   (*args)[i] = (char*)(malloc(tokenLen));
   if ((*args)[i] == NULL)
      exit(1);

   //reset values
   i = 0;
   j = 0;

   //Set arg2 to point to args row head. Transfer values from arg1 to arg2.
   arg2 = ((*args)[i]);
   while(arg1[j] != '\0')
   {
      if (arg1[j] != ' ' && arg1[j] != '\0' && arg1[j] != '\n')
      {
         arg2[k] = arg1[j];
         k++;
      }
      else
      {
         arg2[k] = '\0';
         i++;
         k = 0;
         arg2 = ((*args)[i]);
      }
      j++;

   }

   arg2[k] = '\0';

   if (counter < 1)
   {
      return -1;
   }

   return counter;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try that. Just a quick clarification your for statement in the left trim that ends with the ; without the brackets does that just encompass the rest of the function?

Comment: @cba1067950, I am not sure where your confusion is. BTW, I fixed an error in the function `trimWhiteSpacesLeft`. In my initial post, I used `s[i] = s[j];` It needed to be `s[j] = s[i];`.

Comment: Usually for loops are for(parameters){ code } but you have one that is for(parameters); without brackets and with a semicolon at the end. Sorry I've never seen it that way. I don't know how that works. :(

Comment: @cba1067950, `for ( ; isspace(s[i]); ++i );` is equivalent to `for ( ; isspace(s[i]); ++i ) { }`. It's a `for` loop with an empty body. The only useful thing that happens in the loop is that the value of `i` is the index of the first non-whitespace character in the string at the end of the loop.